# If I follow a madhhab, must I follow them in all matters?

Tags: sunni, madhhab

I am studying different school of thoughts on the Islam. Is it restricted, e.g. if am hanafi then for some matters I cannot opt out following the hambli school of thought? Further to have and harmony and unification cannot I offer namaz with my different school of thoughts friends some time as per this behind particularly with rfadain or without rafadain.

Comment: Having a hard time understanding your question? Are you asking if you can follow different schools at the same time? If so there is no reason why you can't as long as it is proven by the Quran/Sunnah.

Comment: Yes. I mean the same. Can I have some reference so that I can communicte the same to my friend who don't offer prayer together she to different followings of schools hanafi and humbli

Comment: There aren't really any references. Unless someone can prove to you from Quran and Sunnah that you have to follow 1 Mazhab (which is impossible since it didn't even exist during time of prophet), you are free to follow anyone as long as they provide evidence from Quran and Sunnah.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically a question about ijtihād. The classic Islamic view is that every Muslim should follow one particular law school and adhere to its teachings literally and in all its details (taqlīd). Only those with a high degree of knowledge in all fields (hadith, tafsir, fiqh, kalam, Arabic grammar etc.) and a high degree of moral rectitude can attain the status of a mujtahid and establish a new madhhab. Islam is not a “pick and choose” religion.

Comment: A small advice and request, as it is, the question is primarily opinion based, meaning.... what ever answer is posted in here, is highly disputable/debatable/arguable/questionable. As it is to your answer, e.g. doubt is "cite one source which says follow one school". Hence, be careful while answering such type of questions. If you feel there's something wrong with it, flag it as primarily opinion based or with something relevant

Comment: The question of ijtihād is famously discussed by Iman al-Ghazali in his “Al-Mustaṣfā min ‘Ilm al-Uṣūl”.

Comment: yes you're right islam is not a pick and choose religion, but then isnt it contradicting to say we should pick one imam and stay with his school of thought?? to my knowledge all four imams follow the sunnah and so there is no issue with following more than one, For example someone may choose to pray the hanafi way because they find it the right way but do their wudhu according to shafai. there is nothing wrong with it as long as their intentions are pure and they feel what they have chosen is the right path. Everything comes down to ones niyyah (intention)

Comment: There is difference between choosing to follow one particular school and making up your own school from a mish-mash of different opinions. Unless you want to claim to be a mujtahid....

Comment: My point is, if to show unity and uniformity can I offer some time prayer with my friends who are humbli while I am hanafi in their way

Comment: There is no problem with followers of different madhahib praying together at the same time.